# What is the point of adding transation to block chain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, currencies, ecommerce

What is the advantages of adding transaction into the blockchain, instead why can't we go with a normal current way of validating the transaction through dollar, rupees so on.

Is there any advantages of using transaction using blockchain?

Is it more secure or less secure?
 Is it faster or slower? I felt is slower?

Are we going for it is just because we need to use cryptocurrencies?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the advantages of adding transaction into the blockchain

preventing doublespends

for more informatoin look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem (Partition tolerance)